# Parameterize AWS Glue Job for ETL with Date as variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am fairly new to AWS and I am currently exploring it. I was hoping to get an insight or suggestion on how to work with AWS Glue. 
Say I want to run a script that uses `SELECT` for an input and outputs it to `Redshift`. However, I want to to use a parameter for the `WHERE` clause particularly **dates**. In Python and it goes something like:

```
df = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE date between {0}-{1}-{3} AND {4}-{5}-{6}".format(day,month,year,day2,month2,year2)
```

After I get this values, I then use something like a `TEMP table` in Redshift for staging and `LEFT JOIN` in the Fact Table. But I can't seem to figure out how Glue can do this.

I've read some articles/posts that suggests to use a flat file for the variables but I'm not so sure how to do this.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured it out.

First, create a Python Shell Job via AWS Glue then use this code:

```
import sys
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['fromDate', 'toDate'])


print ("VAL1 is : ", args['fromDate'])
print ("VAL2: ", args['fromDate'])

query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN '{}' AND '{}'".format(args['fromDate'], args['toDate')


print(query)
```

The above code is for getting the parameters that are passed in the Job.

Note also that you have to add the **JOB PARAMETERS** in the console as you create your job.

Then you will need a code for passing the parameters to the job. I used `boto3` for this.

```
import boto3
import time

job_name = 'example_job'
client = boto3.client(service_name='glue', region_name='ap-southeast-1',
          endpoint_url='https://glue.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com') 

response = client.start_job_run(JobName=job_name, Arguments={"--fromDate":"1-1-2019",
                                                             "--toDate":"31-12-2019"
                                                            })
status = client.get_job_run(JobName=job_name, RunId=response['JobRunId'])

if status:
    state = status['JobRun']['JobRunState']
    while state not in ['SUCCEEDED']:
        time.sleep(30)
        status = client.get_job_run(JobName=job_name, RunId=response['JobRunId'])
        state = status['JobRun']['JobRunState']
        if state in ['STOPPED', 'FAILED', 'TIMEOUT']:
            raise Exception('Failed to execute glue job: ' + status['JobRun']['ErrorMessage'] + '. State is : ' + state)
```